# pdfinfo doesn't show result when called with exec

Tags: php, pdf, exec, shell-exec

I know that this question is already asked here in StackOverflow, but the answers I found didn't work for me.
The problem is that I'm trying to call `pdfinfo` from Php. I tried with `exec("/usr/bin/pdfinfo /tmp/5a15c44752a9922cb9317c05c3faa5db1608544365.4492.pdf", $output, $exitCode)` (`/usr/bin/pdfinfo` is the absolute path of `pdfinfo`).
The value of `$output` is `[]`and `$exitCode` is `1`.
I also tried to run `exec("/usr/bin/pdfinfo", $output, $exitCode)` to see if `$output` contained the help instruction of the command, but the result was the same as before.
I used all absolute paths to call the command.

The same is also using `echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/pdfinfo /tmp/5a15c44752a9922cb9317c05c3faa5db1608544365.4492.pdf")`which returns NULL.

From the system shell everything is working well, but not from PHP. Can someone help me to find a solution?

Comment: Change `exec(` to: `shell_exec(`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$data = shell_exec("/usr/bin/pdfinfo /tmp/5a15c44752a9922cb9317c05c3faa5db1608544365.4492.pdf");
var_dump($data);
```

If this returns empty, then make sure PHP can access `pdfinfo` to do so try:

```
var_dump(shell_exec("/usr/bin/which pdfinfo"));
```

Comment: The value of $data is NULL